# C - !isalpha treate character of type unsigned char as not alphabetic

Tags: c

The function reads two input from user, both of the input are string but one should contain only numbers and the other should contain only characters. I have a validate function to check if string contains not alphabetic characters.

```
bool checkString( const char inputString[] ){
   
unsigned char inputChar;

bool errorFree = true;

while ( ( inputChar = *inputString ) ){

    if(!isalpha(inputChar)){
         errorFree = false;
    }

     ++inputString;

} 

return errorFree;


}
```

the `!isalpha(inputChar)` keeps treating normal character as not alphabetic, and run set `errorFree` to false. Before calling this function another string input was taken. The full function:

```
void createNewEmployee(char* header, char* records, long size ){

char newID[MAX];

int numberOfRecords = getNumberOfRecords(records);

//printf("num of records: %d",numberOfRecords);

createID(numberOfRecords, (char *) newID );

//printf("%s",newID); 

  char telNum[15];
  char name[40];
  bool telValidated = false;
  bool nameValidated = false;

 while(!telValidated){

        fputs("enter some number: ", stdout);

        fflush(stdout);

        if ( fgets(telNum, sizeof(telNum), stdin) ) {

            int number;

            if ( sscanf(telNum, "%d", &number) == 1 ) {
                
                //   printf("is all number = %d\n", number);

                telValidated = true;
            }

            else{
                printf("enter numbers only\n");
            }
        }
 }

  while(!nameValidated){

        fputs("enter name: ", stdout);

        fflush(stdout);

        if ( fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin) ) {

            if(checkString(name)){
                printf("error Free");
                nameValidated = true;
            }

            else{
                printf("enter characters only!\n");
            }
        }
 }

addNewRecord(newID,"anotherNew,01293073232,newDepartment\n",header, records, size);
```

}

I think it might be because of the input remains in the last fgets got brought into the current fgets?

[image]

Comment: What input are you giving? Didn't you think it could be important? `checkString("Hello")` returns `true`.

Comment: Also what locale are you running with? `isalpha()`s behavior depends on it. You can check via `printf("%s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL, ""));`

Comment: My guess is that the newline character is involved somehow. See [mcve].

Comment: `isalpha()` tests for `[a-zA-Z]`.  If you are using `scanf()`, or `fgets( , ,stdin)` without removing `\n` for example, the test will fail.

Comment: A minimal reproducible example for problems like this includes a `main` routine and all definitions and input necessary to compile and run the program. Readers should be able to copy the source code directly from the question into a file and compile it. This problem was easily solved, but, in the future, also ensure your [mre] is complete.

Comment: `strcat(name,"\0");` is useless. The end of a string is always marked by a terminating null character, so it must already be present in `name` before `strcat` is called.

Comment: `strcat(name,"\0");` makes no sense in your code.

Comment: You may want to get rid of the '\n' character (at the end of the line) after a (successful) call to `fgets` like that:  `name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `fgets` reads a line, it includes the newline character, `'\n'`, in the buffer. The newline character is not alphabetic, so `isalpha` returns false for it.

Fix your code to remove or ignore the newline character in the buffer.

Answer (score 5):

This is why it's always helpful to post your main program too where you test it. My guess is, based on the way you're getting input, maybe you're storing a newline at the end of the string which is not an alphabetic character.

Also, your function has a more elegant solution. As soon as you find an error, there's no need to continue looking through the string. So, just return false as soon as this happens. Technically, it doesn't matter much since your function and mine both are O(N) runtime. However, it's still good to think in this way. What if you had a string of 1000 characters, and the 3rd character was not alphabetical. Why then continue to check all 997 other characters?

```
bool checkString(const char inputString[]) {
    while (*inputString) {
        if (!isalpha(*inputString))
            return false;
        ++inputString;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hopefully you didn't get downvoted by someone adhering to some "functions must only have one return point" rule...

Comment: agreed. I was more just speaking casually but you're right. I'll change that.

Comment: The function body could be reduced to `while (isalpha(*inputString)) ++inputString; return *inputString == '\0';`. Only one test per iteration, instead of two tests.

Comment: Agreed. That's even better than the one I had.

Answer (score 1):

OP's code is likely failing as it still retains a trailing `'\n'`, causing `checkString()` to return incorrectly.

Candidate simplification that does not require prior removal of a `'\n'` from the end of the line:

```
bool checkString(const char inputLine[]) {
  while (isalpha(*(unsigned char*)inputLine)) {
    inputLine++;
  }
  return *inputLine == '\0' || *inputLine == '\n';
}
```

Comment: I would prefer `isalpha((unsigned char) *inputLine)` to `isalpha(* (unsigned char *) inputLine)`. The latter aliases types, which is defined for character types (but is not what we want in the esoteric non-two’s-complement implementation), but is kind of cheating.

Comment: I would also suggest inserting the main answer, that the original code fails due to the presence of a newline character.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In the rare non-two’s-complement implementation, `* (unsigned char *) inputLine` is correct and `(unsigned char) *inputLine` incorrect. `* (unsigned char *) inputLine` fulfills "For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value).".  The other does not as it folds `+0` and `-0` incorrectly  both to the _null character_.

Comment: I see that phrase in 7.24 for `<strings.h>`, but I do not see how it is relevant here. `isalpha` and the routine used to get the data, `fgets`, are not covered by 7.24. `fgets` takes a `char *`, so, if it reads a character with value, say, −3, presumably it puts −3 in a `char`. Then we have to pass that is `isalpha` as an `int` containing a value representable as an `unsigned char` (7.4 1). But then I am stuck; `fgets` is giving us `char` values, but we need to pass `unsigned char` values to `isalpha`, and I do not know anything in the C standard that specifies the semantic mapping…

Comment: … Obviously given a `char c`, we could pass either `(unsigned char) c` or `* (unsigned char *) c` to `isalpha` (or hypothetically other transformations), but I do not know anything that says the character whose code is −3 in a signed `char` is the character whose code is either −3+`UCHAR_MAX`+1 in an `unsigned char` or the `char` bits for −3 reinterpreted as an `unsigned char`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `fgets()` acts as if reading an `unsigned char` due to "The byte input functions read characters from the stream as if by successive calls to the fgetc function.".  More later GTG.

Comment: Okay, `fgets` gets an `unsigned char` value. Then it sticks it in the `char` array we passed it. As if by assignment? As if by `memcpy` of the bits? This is fun, a new hole in the C standard? If it is by assignment, that introduces the implementation-defined conversion to signed integer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil reading an `unsigned char` into a `char`:  When `char` is _unsigned_ `char`, passing by assignment or `memcpy()` is the same - regardless of encoding.  When `char` is _signed_ `char`, (and 2's compliment and implementation-defined conversion is wrap-around) passing by assignment or `memcpy()` is also the same. Of what remains - I know of no current implementation.  Thus the `(unsigned char) *inputLine` vs. `* (unsigned char *) inputLine` becomes moot.  Please advise if you ever know or here of one.  I'd like to know how they handle(d) this.